# What is the meaning of "raw power"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In the *What If?* post [Yoda](https://what-if.xkcd.com/3/), the author writes:

> Yoda’s greatest display of **raw power** in the original trilogy came when he lifted Luke’s X-Wing from the swamp.

What does *raw power* mean? I cannot find any useful example of this phrase in Google. I think it's similar to potential energy in physics context, but I'm not sure about that.

According to [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/raw_1) a raw emotion or quality is strong and natural, but not controlled or developed. So I think the same can be applied to power. However, Yoda is known to be a master, so his power cannot be uncontrolled or undeveloped, though I admit that I haven't watched the whole series.

Comment: [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/raw) supplies an example: **raw** Feelings or qualities that are raw are natural and difficult to control:
_We were struck by the raw energy/power of the dancers' performances._ // 
_Her emotions are still a bit raw after her painful divorce._ //// See also [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/raw):  ...4
c :  not tempered :  unbridled <raw power>

Comment: It refers to 'just the power', with the connotation that there is a lot of it. It isn't that the power has been filtered, enhanced, diluted or paced etc. It is 'just' power. Sometimes, you can do a lot with a little. Other times, you simply have a lot. This is a reference to the latter.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That doesn't seem to be how it's being used in the quote. Yoda's power is anything but difficult to control. That sense of *raw* would better describe Luke's abilities when he first met Yoda. Or have you not seen the Star Wars movies, so you don't understand the context?

Comment: @Barmar I should have qualified that I was addressing OP's 'According to Macmillan Dictionary a raw emotion or quality is strong and natural, but not controlled or developed. So I think the same can be applied to power.' // I'd say that the usage here is intended merely to conjure up the notion of a vast amount of power. Sadly, I can't find a dictionary that licenses this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Raw power* has no strict physical meaning; it's descriptive. As Lawrence points out, it simply means the bearer (Yoda) commands an amount of power large enough that he can afford to exercise it without control.

Suppose we're Jedi knights, and a large mob of droids is charging at us. I might have moderate power with high control: perhaps I can overload the power core of a droid in the middle, creating an EMP that temporarily stuns the rest of the mob. You might have moderate power and moderate control: you can knock over the front droid, and hope it knocks over a few more droids behind it (maybe you just enjoy using your saber more).

Yoda has high power and high control: he could perform a refined move like I did, but may instead choose to employ that power in unrefined, *raw* form, bowling over the entire group, and maybe sweeping them all back several hundred feet.